# Modify the number format of results table from QGis Group Stats Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

The Group Stats plugin it great, I would like to know if it is possible to make the plugin yields its statistics values in other format that is not the scientific one. I know I can export the data and then import them into a spreadsheet but what I want is to quickly visualize the results in a thousands-like notation.

I am using QGis 2.18.21 - 32 bits, Windows 10

Comment: Only way to achieve this would be to modify the [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) yourself as the author no longer seems to maintain it. How are your coding skills? :)

Comment: I can give it a try but not sure about the author.